# Why is my middleware executed twice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I wrote a middleware in express.js/node.js that checks the session and if it finds a user ID, shows the user's menu , or else, the default menu.

Every page request checks for an id and fetches user data from the database (id, name, category etc.)

Here is the middleware:

```
module.exports = function(req,res,next){
    console.log("INSIDE SESSION HANDLER");

    if(!req.session.uid) return next();
    else{   
        User.get(uid, function(user){
            if (!user) {return next(err);}
            else{
                req.user = res.locals.user = user;
                next();
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Then, ejs checks locals and if there is an ID, shows the user's menu.

I was loading a testing page that I didnt use the socket.io library, but forgot to delete the `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %> , <%= settings.title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>//<== SHOULD DELETE THIS
    <h1>Login</h1>
        <%include menu%> //<== USES EJS TO CHECK LOCALS AND SHOW DEFAULT OR USER MENU
  </head>
  <body>
```

When the `script src` line was not there the middleware was executing once (saw `console.log("INSIDE SESSION HANDLER");` only once).

When the `script src` line was there, was giving  a 404 error apparently, but the middleware was executing twice ( saw the `console.log("INSIDE SESSION HANDLER");` twice).

Here is the output from `console.log`:

```
INSIDE SESSION HANDLER
GET / 304 66ms //page
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 11ms
INSIDE SESSION HANDLER //again
GET /socket.io/socket.io.js 404 28ms - 1.04kb
GET /multimedia/01.jpg 304 4ms //images...
GET /multimedia/02.jpg 304 5ms
```

I want to really understand requests/responses and middleware. So why this is happening? Why is this middleware executed twice because of the 404 error? Does the 404 error response cause the middleware to execute twice?

Thanks

EDIT

I use the middleware in app.js like so:

```
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/node_modules/static-favicon/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({resave:'false', saveUninitialized:'false', secret:'secret'}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('multimedia', __dirname + '/public/multimedia');

app.use(handler); //<= THE MIDDLEWARE IN QUESTION


app.use(messages);
app.get('/', routes.list);
app.get('/register', register.form);
app.post('/register', register.submitit);
```

Comment: It could be that `express.static` couldn't serve the file that was requested, so it continued the request chain (aka '`next()`'), in which case it would run the `app.use(handler)` middleware and attempt to match against other routes lower down, none-which apply so it shows a 404. In other words, It logs once for the actual page load, and once for the 404.

Comment: I've written the above comment up in an answer below after testing that this is the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why your middleware is getting run twice is that it is being run once for the initial request, and once for the 404 (the static script that doesn't exist).

If `express.static` can find a file, it sends the response with the appropriate file, if it can't find the correct file (as is the case with you) it calls `next()` which attempts to match the request to other routes, running any other middleware that are defined below `express.static`.

In other words, if `express.static` does find the file to serve, middleware below it will not run. In your case the middleware runs once for the actual request and once trying to find the file or a correct route to serve as a response.

This can be observed by logging the `req.path` for a normal static file, and one that doesn't exist:

app.js -

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(function(req, res, next){
  console.log('Requested path: %s', req.path);
  next();
})
```

layout.hbs (renders for '/') -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' /> <!-- exists -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/foo.css' /> <!-- doesn't exist -->
  </head>
  <body>
    {{{body}}}
  </body>
</html>
```

We'll see that the middleware will only log the request path for the initial request and for the 404, but not the static file. e.g:

```
Requested path: /
Requested path: /stylesheets/foo.css
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I guess in third paragraph, first line, by `does fine the file` you mean `does find the file` ?

Answer (score -1):

Where are you applying this middleware?

If for instance you have

```
app.use(handler)
```

where `handler` is of the form `function (req, res, next)`, it will be applied to **every** request (with any HTTP verb). Alternatively,

```
app.get('/some/route', handler)
```

where the `handler` will apply everywhere below `/some/route` (E.g. `/some/route/any/deepness`).

So my guess is that you are **over applying your middleware function** (I'm interchanging *handler* and *middleware*, they have the same function signature - perhaps *handler* is more suited to functions which send a response and middleware to those who call `next()`). But it is hard to say without the context of how this middleware is being applied.

See [Writing Middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) and the other guides provided by Express.

PS. You dont need to `return next()` in middleware. Just `next()`.

Comment: I updated my question, showing how the middleware is defined in the `app.js` . Nice answer, I get what you are saying, but I dont think I overapply it because I define it and then every other definition that follows it, uses it. How is this related with the 404 error and the fact that middleware executes twice? Thanks

Comment: @slevin when you request something that doesn't exist, the middleware runs (since it runs on everything that isn't static), followed by the 404 handler that prints the 404 page.